# In a React.js APP, I caught this: TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a webpage that has a calculator on it with react.js. But this message keeps showing up and I don't think moving the relative JS codes to to the end of my scripts would help (or maybe I didn't find a proper way to put it to the end), because react.js requires a return part at the end.

How to fix it?

These are the relative codes:

```
// HTML part (in JSX style)
    <button class="btn" id="compute" >Compute</button>
    <button class="btn" id="reset"   >Reset</button>

// JS part
    var show = document.getElementById("show")
    var btnCompute = document.getElementById("compute")
    var btnReset = document.getElementById("reset")

    btnCompute.onclick = function () {
    // function toCompute () {
        if(expStr){
            show.innerHTML = computeSuffix(nifix2Suffix(strSplit(expStr)));
            expStr = "";
        }
    }

    btnReset.onclick = function () {
    // function toReset () {

        show.innerHTML = "type in here";
        expStr = "";
    }
```

And the error page is like this:
[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwmwu.png)

The entire codes are as below:

```
import React from "react";

class Calculator extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            equ: '',
            answer: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Bind <li> to event
        var liList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        var expStr = "";

        for (let i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {
            let li = liList[i];
            li.onclick = () => {
                // 获取中缀表达式（nifix expression）
                expStr += this.textContent;

                // 在页面上显示表达式
                show.innerHTML = expStr;

                // console.log(expStr);
            }
        }

        // 当点击 'Compute' 按钮（id='compute'）时
        var show = document.getElementById("show")
        var btnCompute = document.getElementById("compute")
        var btnReset = document.getElementById("reset")

        btnCompute.onclick = function () {
            // function toCompute () {
            if (expStr) {
                show.innerHTML = computeSuffix(nifix2Suffix(strSplit(expStr)));
                expStr = "";
            }
        }

        btnReset.onclick = function () {
            // function toReset () {

            show.innerHTML = "请输入计算式";
            expStr = "";
        }

        // 按键触发事件
        document.onkeypress = function (evt) {
            // 获取按键值
            console.log(evt.key)

            if (evt.key === "Enter") {
                // 'Enter'
                show.innerHTML = computeSuffix(nifix2Suffix(strSplit(expStr)))
                expStr = ""
            } else {
                // 其他按键
                expStr += evt.key
                show.innerHTML = expStr
            }

            // console.log(expStr, "expStr")
        }


        // ======================
        // nifix exp: string => array
        // ======================

        // 表达式分割
        function strSplit(expStr) {
            // 操作数左下标
            var index = 0, list = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < expStr.length; i++) {
                // 忽略空格
                if (expStr[i] === " ") {
                    continue;
                }

                // 如果是操作符
                // 1. 先将操作符前的操作数加入到数组中(判断是否为空)
                // 2. 再将操作符本身加入到数组中
                // 3. 将左下标后移一位
                if ("+-*/()".indexOf(expStr[i]) !== -1) {
                    if (expStr.slice(index, i)) {
                        list.push(expStr.slice(index, i));
                    }
                    list.push(expStr[i]);

                    index = i + 1;
                }
            }

            // 循环结束判断是否存在最后一位操作数，存在，加入数组
            if (i === expStr.length && expStr.slice(index, i)) {
                list.push(expStr.slice(index, i));
            }
            return list;
        }

        // =====================
        // 中缀表达式 => 后缀表达式
        // =====================
        function nifix2Suffix(exlist) {

            // 栈的创建
            var opStack = {
                value: [],
                push: function (item) { this.value.push(item) },
                pop: function () { return this.value.pop() },
                peek: function () { return this.value[this.value.length - 1] },
                isEmpty: function () { return this.value.length === 0 },
                size: function () { return this.value.length }
            }

            // 定义优先级判断
            var dicPriority = {};
            dicPriority['*'] = 3;
            dicPriority['/'] = 3;
            dicPriority['+'] = 2;
            dicPriority['-'] = 2;
            dicPriority['('] = 1;

            // 列表存储转换的后缀表达式
            var suffix = [];

            for (var i of exlist) {

                if ("+-*/()".indexOf(i) === -1) {
                    // 操作数直接添加到列表中
                    suffix.push(i)

                } else if (i === "(") {
                    opStack.push(i)
                } else if (i === ")") {
                    while (opStack.peek() !== "(") {
                        suffix.push(opStack.pop())
                    }
                    opStack.pop()
                } else {
                    while (!opStack.isEmpty() && dicPriority[opStack.peek()] >= dicPriority[i]) {
                        suffix.push(opStack.pop())
                    }
                    opStack.push(i)
                }
            }

            while (!opStack.isEmpty() && opStack.peek() !== "") {
                suffix.push(opStack.pop())
            }

            // console.log(suffix, "后缀数组")

            return suffix
        }

        // var prefix = "a+b*c+(d*e+f)*g"

        // console.log(nifix2Suffix(prefix))
        // 检验栈对象是否成功
        // console.log(opStack.value)
        // console.log(opStack.push(5))
        // console.log(opStack.value)
        // console.log(opStack.push(10))
        // console.log(opStack.peek())
        // console.log(opStack.isEmpty())
        // console.log(opStack.size())
        // console.log(opStack.value)



        // ============
        // 后缀表达式计算
        // ============
        function computeSuffix(exlist) {

            // 如果接收的是空数组
            // 代表表达式错误 / 用户未输入
            if (exlist.length === 0) {
                return "请输入正确的表达式"
            }

            // 栈的创建
            var opStack = {
                value: [],
                push: function (item) { this.value.push(item) },
                pop: function () { return this.value.pop() },
                peek: function () { return this.value[this.value.length - 1] },
                isEmpty: function () { return this.value.length === 0 },
                size: function () { return this.value.length }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < exlist.length; i++) {
                // 遍历表达式
                switch (exlist[i]) {
                    case "+":
                        opStack.push(opStack.pop() + opStack.pop())
                        break
                    case "-":
                        var jianshu = opStack.pop()
                        opStack.push(opStack.pop() - jianshu)
                        break
                    case "*":
                        opStack.push(opStack.pop() * opStack.pop())
                        break
                    case "/":
                        var chushu = opStack.pop()
                        opStack.push(opStack.pop() / chushu)
                        break
                    default:
                        opStack.push(parseFloat(exlist[i]))
                }
            }

            var result = opStack.pop()

            // console.log(result, "后缀结果")

            if (isNaN(result)) {
                return "计算出错啦！"
            }
            return result % 1 === 0 ? result : result.toFixed(2)
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='card cal2'>
                <h2>Calculator</h2>

                <div class="box">
                    <div id="show"></div>
                    <ul class="grid btn-grid">
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>+</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                        <li>6</li>
                        <li>-</li>
                        <li>7</li>
                        <li>8</li>
                        <li>9</li>
                        <li>*</li>
                        <li>(</li>
                        <li>0</li>
                        <li>)</li>
                        <li>/</li>
                        <li>.</li>
                        <button class="btn" id='compute' >Compute</button>
                        <button class="btn" id='reset'   onClick={this.toReset}>Reset</button>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Calculator;
```

I've edited my code to this version:

```
import React from "react";

class Calculator extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            equ: '',
            answer: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Bind <li> to event
        var liList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        var expStr = "";

        for (let i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {
            let li = liList[i];
            li.onclick = () => {
                // 获取中缀表达式（nifix expression）
                expStr += this.textContent;

                // 在页面上显示表达式
                show.innerHTML = expStr;

                // console.log(expStr);
            }
        }

        // 当点击 'Compute' 按钮（id='compute'）时
        var show = document.getElementById("show")
        var btnCompute = document.getElementById("compute")
        var btnReset = document.getElementById("reset")

        btnCompute.onclick = function () {
            // function toCompute () {
            if (expStr) {
                show.innerHTML = computeSuffix(nifix2Suffix(strSplit(expStr)));
                expStr = "";
            }
        }

        btnReset.onclick = function () {
            // function toReset () {

            show.innerHTML = "请输入计算式";
            expStr = "";
        }

        // 按键触发事件
        document.onkeypress = function (evt) {
            // 获取按键值
            console.log(evt.key)

            if (evt.key === "Enter") {
                // 'Enter'
                show.innerHTML = computeSuffix(nifix2Suffix(strSplit(expStr)))
                expStr = ""
            } else {
                // 其他按键
                expStr += evt.key
                show.innerHTML = expStr
            }

            // console.log(expStr, "expStr")
        }


        // ======================
        // nifix exp: string => array
        // ======================

        // 表达式分割
        function strSplit(expStr) {
            // 操作数左下标
            var index = 0, list = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < expStr.length; i++) {
                // 忽略空格
                if (expStr[i] === " ") {
                    continue;
                }

                // 如果是操作符
                // 1. 先将操作符前的操作数加入到数组中(判断是否为空)
                // 2. 再将操作符本身加入到数组中
                // 3. 将左下标后移一位
                if ("+-*/()".indexOf(expStr[i]) !== -1) {
                    if (expStr.slice(index, i)) {
                        list.push(expStr.slice(index, i));
                    }
                    list.push(expStr[i]);

                    index = i + 1;
                }
            }

            // 循环结束判断是否存在最后一位操作数，存在，加入数组
            if (i === expStr.length && expStr.slice(index, i)) {
                list.push(expStr.slice(index, i));
            }
            return list;
        }

        // =====================
        // 中缀表达式 => 后缀表达式
        // =====================
        function nifix2Suffix(exlist) {

            // 栈的创建
            var opStack = {
                value: [],
                push: function (item) { this.value.push(item) },
                pop: function () { return this.value.pop() },
                peek: function () { return this.value[this.value.length - 1] },
                isEmpty: function () { return this.value.length === 0 },
                size: function () { return this.value.length }
            }

            // 定义优先级判断
            var dicPriority = {};
            dicPriority['*'] = 3;
            dicPriority['/'] = 3;
            dicPriority['+'] = 2;
            dicPriority['-'] = 2;
            dicPriority['('] = 1;

            // 列表存储转换的后缀表达式
            var suffix = [];

            for (var i of exlist) {

                if ("+-*/()".indexOf(i) === -1) {
                    // 操作数直接添加到列表中
                    suffix.push(i)

                } else if (i === "(") {
                    opStack.push(i)
                } else if (i === ")") {
                    while (opStack.peek() !== "(") {
                        suffix.push(opStack.pop())
                    }
                    opStack.pop()
                } else {
                    while (!opStack.isEmpty() && dicPriority[opStack.peek()] >= dicPriority[i]) {
                        suffix.push(opStack.pop())
                    }
                    opStack.push(i)
                }
            }

            while (!opStack.isEmpty() && opStack.peek() !== "") {
                suffix.push(opStack.pop())
            }

            // console.log(suffix, "后缀数组")

            return suffix
        }

        // var prefix = "a+b*c+(d*e+f)*g"

        // console.log(nifix2Suffix(prefix))
        // 检验栈对象是否成功
        // console.log(opStack.value)
        // console.log(opStack.push(5))
        // console.log(opStack.value)
        // console.log(opStack.push(10))
        // console.log(opStack.peek())
        // console.log(opStack.isEmpty())
        // console.log(opStack.size())
        // console.log(opStack.value)



        // ============
        // 后缀表达式计算
        // ============
        function computeSuffix(exlist) {

            // 如果接收的是空数组
            // 代表表达式错误 / 用户未输入
            if (exlist.length === 0) {
                return "请输入正确的表达式"
            }

            // 栈的创建
            var opStack = {
                value: [],
                push: function (item) { this.value.push(item) },
                pop: function () { return this.value.pop() },
                peek: function () { return this.value[this.value.length - 1] },
                isEmpty: function () { return this.value.length === 0 },
                size: function () { return this.value.length }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < exlist.length; i++) {
                // 遍历表达式
                switch (exlist[i]) {
                    case "+":
                        opStack.push(opStack.pop() + opStack.pop())
                        break
                    case "-":
                        var jianshu = opStack.pop()
                        opStack.push(opStack.pop() - jianshu)
                        break
                    case "*":
                        opStack.push(opStack.pop() * opStack.pop())
                        break
                    case "/":
                        var chushu = opStack.pop()
                        opStack.push(opStack.pop() / chushu)
                        break
                    default:
                        opStack.push(parseFloat(exlist[i]))
                }
            }

            var result = opStack.pop()

            // console.log(result, "后缀结果")

            if (isNaN(result)) {
                return "计算出错啦！"
            }
            return result % 1 === 0 ? result : result.toFixed(2)
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='card cal2'>
                <h2>Calculator</h2>

                <div class="box">
                    <div id="show"></div>
                    <ul class="grid btn-grid">
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>+</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                        <li>6</li>
                        <li>-</li>
                        <li>7</li>
                        <li>8</li>
                        <li>9</li>
                        <li>*</li>
                        <li>(</li>
                        <li>0</li>
                        <li>)</li>
                        <li>/</li>
                        <li>.</li>
                        <button class="btn" id='compute' >Compute</button>
                        <button class="btn" id='reset'   onClick={this.toReset}>Reset</button>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Calculator;
```

The previous problem was solved, but here comes a new problem. When click on the `<li>`items, it shows undefined, but I didn't change that part of code. Why would this happen?

Comment: whenever possible, you should use React Events, rather than trying to add `.onclick` events by hand.

Comment: in your code, you have some handlers using React style and others that are not.  The ones that are not using React Events are the ones that are causing the errors.  Is there a specific reason that you chose to define them in this way?

Comment: Still learning and not familiar with it right now, hhh, but I'll surly try this way later. Thanks.

Comment: basically, in React, using `onClick={calculate}` is good, using `btnReset.onclick = function ()` is bad.  define a `reset` function, and use `onClick={reset}`.

Comment: Well, the not react style part is what I searched from other websites. I'm studying the way he handles the nifix expression and how to compute. I wrote the react style parts myself. When I was trying to apply those non-react codes into my script, problems occured.

Comment: OK, I am trying your method now. I'll let you know whether it works or not. Thank you.

Comment: I use the ```componentDidMount()``` method. The old problem has been solved, but a new problem occurred. Another question is, I am trying to use React Events, but I couldn't find a way to use functions outside ```componentDidMount()```.

Answer (score 0):

The time you are trying to get button references by invoking getElementById, the UI is not rendered yet. That is why they are null.
You should get those reference after mounting of the component.

Comment: I can get your idea, and thank you for answering. But how can I set it to build the UI first and then run the script? It seems that in react.js, the return part that includes the html tags should be the last part of my script.

Comment: OK, I have added the codes. Thank you again.

Comment: As commented by  Claies you should use React Events instead of setting eventListeners after getting references. Though one quick solution can be put your code in useEffect hook. example -   useEffect(function() { ...put your code...});

Answer (score 0):

Use React.createRef

In constructor:

```
this.computeRef = React.createRef();
```

In return html:

```
<button class="btn" id="compute" ref={this.computeRef}>Compute</button>
```

While accessing:

```
const computeRefNode = this.computeRef.current;
```